# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive with D3 js

Tags: d3.js, zooming, preventdefault

I'm working with D3.js library. I wan't to make zoom in SVG file.
When I'm zooming in or out. Has a lot of errors emit into console like this:

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312`

This is my code.

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" data="seatMap.svg"></object>

<script type="text/javascript">
  'use strict';

  var obj = document.getElementById('map');
  var svgDoc = obj.getSVGDocument();
  var svg = d3.select(svgDoc).select('svg');
  var g = d3.select(svgDoc).select('#seat-map');

  svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on('zoom', zoomed));

  function zoomed() {
    g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
  }
</script>
```

I already research and try many times but still get are errors.
Anyone know how to resolve? Thank you.